# Duplicate Nugets

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I have a .NET MVC3 application, running on VS 2010
I was trying to update to VS2017 and .NET MVC5 and I got hit with the following error (There are duplicate packages).
I went to the Package.config file to find the followings;

```
<packages>
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="2.5.2" />
  <package id="FluentNHibernate" version="1.2.0.712" />
  <package id="Iesi.Collections" version="3.2.0.4000" />
  <package id="NHibernate" version="3.1.0.4000" /> 
  <package id="NHibernate" version="3.2.0.4000" /> 
  <package id="NHibernate.Castle" version="3.1.0.4000" /> 
  <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.0.12054" />
</packages>
```

I understand that I have duplicate id “NHibernate” and when I tried to comment the older version of them it did not do anything.
I am not able to update my Nuget because of this error.
Do you know what might be the problem?.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the offending id line, saving, then rebuilding? You can also try using [the reinstall command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages#using-update-package) to reset things.

Comment: I tried doing so, however, I am stilling getting the above message. The duplicate package error does not allow me to update my Nugets. ... Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you could remove duplicated packages from package manager, then you should come back to config file and remove those package names (if exists). Now reinstall the packages and build the project.